# Python: Print list sequence

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to write a clean code in python to print something like:

```
Introduce the number of lists you want to have: 3
Introduce how many numbers you want it to have: 3
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
[1,2,3]
Introduce how many numbers you want it to have: 4
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 5
Number: 9
[1,2,5,9]
Introduce how many numbers you want it to have: 5
Number: 1
Number: 7
Number: 2
Number: 8
Number: 3
[1,7,2,8,3]
```

This is my try at it, but it only works for a list, as I don't know how to add multiple lists:

```
v1=[]
n=input ("Introduce how many numbers you want it to have: ")
def introdTast():
      print("Introduce the numbers: ")
      for i in range(0,n):
      v1.append(input())

introdTast()
print "v1 =",v1
print "\n"
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can you write the code? I tried a few ways .. but I only get errors ..

Comment: Well then, you should post the code you have and the errors you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is here: [**The Python Tutorial**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

However, here you go:

```
lists = int(raw_input('Introduce the number of lists you want to have: '))
for i in xrange(lists):
    numbers = int(raw_input('Introduce how many numbers you want it to have: '))
    l = []
    for j in xrange(numbers):
        l.append(int(input('Number: ')))
    print l
```